# Send files over angular Http sequentially (serially) one by one in angular using rxjs concatMap() operator

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, rxjs, observable, httpclient

I'm trying to upload files using a prefetchedUrl to S3 bucket sequentially.

generateUrl() function used to generate a unique url for each file to be upload. It takes a uniqueId (which is static) and a filename

```
  generateUrl(uniqueId, file) {
    var ext = (file.name).split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
    console.log(ext);
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/secure/upload/signed/${uniqueId}?filename=${file.name}.${ext}`);
  }
```

fileUpload() function used to upload files. It takes unique url generated by the generateUrl() function and a file to be uploaded.

```
  uploadFilesByLink(url, file) {
    return this.http.put(url,file, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": file.type },
      reportProgress: true,
      observe:'events'
    })
  }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is -

```
this.filesArray.forEach((file,index)=>{
     this.uploadsService.generateUrl(this.uniqueId, file)
        .pipe(
          concatMap(res1 => this.uploadsService.uploadFilesByLink(res1.url, file))
        ).subscribe(res2 => console.log(this.filesArray.indexOf(file),res2));
     })
```

But this is uploading files parallely.
Please help.
I have tried many solutions on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way and its working.

upload.service.ts

```
  generateUrl(uniqueId, file) {
    console.log(file);
    var ext = (file.name).split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
    console.log(ext);
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/secure/upload/signed/${uniqueId}?filename=${file.name}.${ext}`)
      .pipe(
        map(
          res => {
           return {
             "url": res.url,
             "file":file
            }
          }
        )
      )
  }
```

upload-home.component.ts

```
 this.subscription = from(this.filesArray).pipe(
      concatMap(file => this.uploadsService.generateUrl(this.uniqueId, file)),
      concatMap(response => this.uploadsService.uploadFilesByLink(response.url, response.file))
    ).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          console.log(' sent');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
          console.log(' response header has been received');
          break;
        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
          // this.eventLoaded = event.loaded;
          this.progressInfo[this.it] = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
          console.log(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
          break;
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          // this.eventLoaded1 += this.eventLoaded;
          this.it++;
          console.log('it', this.it);

          this.responseArray.push(this.it);

          console.log('Uploaded');
          console.log(this.responseArray);

          // console.log(this.responseArray.length, this.filesArray.length);

          if (this.responseArray.length === this.filesArray.length) {
            console.log(this.emailOptions);

            if (this.emailOptions) {
              const controls = this.formGroup.controls;
              const from_email = controls.email_from.value;
              const to_email = controls.email_to.value;
              const message = controls.message.value;
              this.uploadsService.uploadFilesByEmail({
                "from_email": from_email,
                "to_email": [to_email],
                "message": message
              }, this.uniqueId).then(res => {
                this.uploadsService.afterUpdatingEmail(this.uniqueId).then(res => {
                  console.log('Uploaded By Email');

                  console.log(res);
                  this.it = 0;
                  this.filesArray = [];
                  this.fileSize = 0;
                  this.responseArray = [];
                  this.requestArrayLink = [];
                  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
                  this.successScreen = true;
                })
              })
            }
            else {
              this.it = 0;
              this.filesArray = [];
              this.fileSize = 0;
              this.responseArray = [];
              this.requestArrayLink = [];
              this.subscription.unsubscribe();
              console.log('Uploaded by Link');
              this.successScreen = true;
            }
          }
          else {
            console.log(this.it, 'uploaded');
          }
      }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function along with the [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) operator. `from` emits items in an array one by one as opposed to RxJS [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) function which doesn't flatten the input and emits the array as a single notification.

Try the following

```js
from(this.filesArray).pipe(
  concatMap(file => {
    const url = this.uploadsService.generateUrl(this.uniqueId, file);
    return this.uploadsService.uploadFilesByLink(url, file);
  })
).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => // always good practice to handle HTTP errors,
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

Comment: Hii Michael, thanks for tha answer.
But I'm getting error  as property ** 'url' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.**
which I guess is okay because In uploadFilesByLink(res.url, file) , res is actually the response I get after subscribing to generateUrl(this.uniqueId, file).

Please help.

Comment: I based on your statement `uploadFilesByLink(res1.url, file)`. But seeing your function `generateUrl()` it doesn't return an object with the `url` property like you're trying to obtain it. Instead directly do `this.uploadsService.uploadFilesByLink(url, file)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It returns an object with the url property and that url needs to be passed to the uploadFilebyLink function.

Comment: From the error message from your first comment, you're clearly not returning an object but an Observable. You need to provide the actual function if you wish to find the issue.